# How to optimise Google Translate API calls to translate multiple words in a single request

Tags: optimization, google-translate

Everyone. Recently Google Translate Is Integrated Into My Project, Which Plays The Role Of Translating Some Product Names, Product Descriptions, Product Related Category Names. But Cause There Are Plenty Of Products In My Database(And Increased Quickly), Google Translate Api Would Cost Considerable Money.

I Want To Translate By Google As Less As Possible. In The Translation, Many Words Are Same Among Many Products, For Example : 阿迪达斯 - Adidas, 苹果 - iphone, 篮球 - Basketball, Bla Bla..... I Wanna Do Some Tricks, But Find No Idea.
Did Anyone Encounter Such Questions?

Any Help Would Be Appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you need is actually the ability to reuse translation at the string or substring level (in other words, per database entry). You can't really do that with Google, that I know of. You've got a few options, as I see it:

- You could switch over to Microsoft Translator and use their methods
  that allow you to place translations yourself, such as  their
  Collaborative Translation feature that lets you override the MT with 
  a preferred translation and even to vote translations up/down. Quality here will be broadly comparable to Google (I often find it better), and you have methods at your disposal that allow this override. Also, unlike Google, the Microsoft API is free up to a certain volume. Take a look:
  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/developers.aspx
- Microsoft  also has a unique feature called the Microsoft Translator Hub, which can use your terminology, for example, for translations. However,depending on how you implemented any solution with Microsoft, you might still have the problem   that you are making more calls out to Microsoft than you'd like, and, moreover, that "matching" only takes place at the level of a whole record or string, so it would not hit the case of shared linguistic elements being concatenated into one string.
- There's a commercial offering called GeoFluent (full disclosure--I am the product manager for this product, so I'm clearly biased :)) that works with Microsoft Translator but provides pre and post translation processing that can deal with sub-segment  and may reduce the volume you are therefore putting through translation each time.  It could make sense if, as you mention, you are rapidly adding to your database. Of course, this is a commercial offering too, so you'd have to balance the costs. 
  Let me know if this helps, and happy to answer any other questions you have.
  Marcus

Answer (score 0):

There is a PHP sample here : http://weblite.ca/svn/dataface/modules/tm/trunk/lib/googleTranslatePlugin.php

That allows you to send and array and return an array.

> array(source=>target) getTranslations()
>
> - translates all of the user provided strings into the target language using the Google Translate API and returns an array of source=>target
>     strings.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but it is not what i want, i can get the google translate result and parse it. May Be I didn't make my question clear enough.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, but it is not what i want, i can get the google translate result and parse it. May Be I didn't make my question clear enough. eg. two products' names are as following : "2013春季阿迪达斯篮球鞋", another one is : "新款匹克低帮篮球鞋". "篮球鞋" exists in both names, here are only two record, don't mention hundreds of thousands products. What I want is query less, your array solution is not applicative.